# Resources for Performance testing

Tags: asp.net, performance

Our small concern is entrusted with creating an Application on ASP.NET with client-server model. As we are almost done with the development we are creating a small team for Performance test. I have googled in the net about the topic but without much help. If anyone of you can share 'How, What and Why' about perf test, it would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good book about [caring to Performance](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/care_about_performance_ebook.htm) and Some of [Performance Best Practices](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998512.aspx)  find here. I think this practices shows your Why / What and how to create high performance application.

in this link you can find [10 tips for creating High-Performance Web Application](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/care_about_performance_ebook.htm)

[1](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/care_about_performance_ebook.htm): http://10 Tips for Writing High-Performance Web Applications